# MSBuild failed with Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(515,3): error XA1023: Using the DX DEX Compiler is not supported

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my xamarin.forms project MSBuild task failed with the error

```
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(515,3): error XA1023: 
Using the DX DEX Compiler is not supported. Please set the DEX compiler to 'd8' in the Visual Studio project property pages or edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'AndroidDexTool' MSBuild property to 'd8'.
```

Tried to change the `AndroidDexTool` to d8 but getting another error as below,

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
```

using,
xamarin.forms 4.5.0.657 and xamarin.android: 12.2.8.3
Target android version Android 12.0
Visual Studio for Mac 8.10.25(build 2)

Comment: Could provide some relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described. I can't get useful tips on the information you have provided.

Comment: @JianweiSun This issue has been fixed. I had to use older r8.jar file from Visual Studio 2019 install location. Thanks for your support.